# Querying for like a list of wildcard variables in a query string

Tags: soql

Trying to build something for a batch job and am hitting an issue when testing in query editor in dev console.

I know you can do something like:

```
String[] stagenames= new string[]{'1%','2%'};
List<opportunity> o = [select id, stagename from opportunity where stagename like :stagenames];
```

So I'm trying to do something similar in dev console Query Editor

```
select id, stagename from opportunity where stagename like ('1%','2%')
```

but its throwing 'Unknown error parsing query'

Is there a syntax issue somewhere that I missed? Or is dynamic soql the only option here and I can't reproduce in Query Editor. Just a bit curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a special feature of the Apex language; SOQL does not have an equivalent feature. The possible conditions you can use are in the [language reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm).